# Charset error while reading ID3 tags

Tags: java, string, mp3, id3, id3v2

I'm trying to retrieve ID3 tags from mp3 files by using [Java ID3Tag Library](http://javamusictag.sourceforge.net/). But I get some errors while retrieving strings with special characters (çáêü...). So I've converted these strings to byte arrays:

```
ID3v2_4 tag=(ID3v2_4) mp3file.getID3v2Tag();
byte [] artBytes=tag.getLeadArtist().getBytes();
for (int i=0;i<artBytes.length;i++){
   System.out.println(artBytes[i]);
}
```

And then I've found that every "unknown" char (as well as the first bytes in the string) has been read as the three-byte sequence -17 -65 -67 ("�" in the string). Also, after each letter there is a byte 0. So, if I want to read "Blue Öyster Cult" ,I get something like "��B l u e � y s t e r   C u l t".

What can I do to normalize these strings?

[EDIT]

- A few mp3 files with special characters are displayed correctly.
- Reading from charsets like US_ASCII or ISO_8859_1 will cause the char � to be displayed as byte 63.

Comment: Probably a bug in the library, or an invalid MP3 file (caused by the program that generated it having a bug).

Comment: Does the ID3 tag show up correctly with a different program -- i.e. your music player?

Comment: Yes, they are displayed correctly in other programs.

Comment: You could improve your question by including all the code you are using to read the tag, using a specific encoding when converting to byte array (`getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`) and giving  a complete example output (e.g. Arrays.toString(artByte) and tag.getLeadArtist()).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As immibis said, it probably was a bug in the library. I ended up using the [mp3agic](https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic) library, and  everything worked fine.